# Spoon PDI Kettle crashes after cairo package update

Tags: pentaho, cairo, kettle, pdi

I just solved a problem which took me way too much time so I thought I share the solution here in case anyone else is biting bricks because of this.

what happened?
I run Pentaho Data Integration 5.2 on CentOS 6.6.
It worked like a charme until I ran yum update the last time.

Now when I was using the graphical interface spoon crashes immediately when I would open an element (e.g. table input) and try to select the query text.
Sometimes it leaves a crash message sometimes not.

Here is the error message:

```
java: cairo-misc.c:380: _cairo_operator_bounded_by_source: Assertion `NOT_REACHED' failed.
./spoon.sh: line 206:  8922 Aborted (core dumped) "$_PENTAHO_JAVA" $OPT -jar "$STARTUP" -lib $LIBPATH "${1+$@}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine remembered a quite similar problem he had with his Eclipse and found the solution for me which was to add the following line into spoon.sh into OPT variable:
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false

It now looks like:
OPT="$OPT $PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.library.path=$LIBPATH -DKETTLE_HOME=$KETTLE_HOME -DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=$KETTLE_REPOSITORY -DKETTLE_USER=$KETTLE_USER -DKETTLE_PASSWORD=$KETTLE_PASSWORD -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=$KETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES -DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=$KETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT -DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=$KETTLE_JNDI_ROOT -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false"

Now it works again. 
Apparently the problem was with the cairo graphics package.
I really love it when stuff doesn't work anymore after updating..

Comment: It's pretty horrible how unreliable spoon can be especially on Linux. there is a good reference to fixing some of the issues here: http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/installing-pentaho-kettle-depencencies.html